# reusable condition/expression classes

Tags: java, expression, functor

I have needed in several occasions some classes to represent and manipulate conditions (typically in a UI so the user builds a query by combining different condition types and then the code can transform that depending on the underlying system to be queried, for example lucene and a db). I searched all over for a reusable set of classes, I am sure this has to be used in many existing places (all the expression languages for starters) but could not find anything easily usable. I ended up coding both times myself, but felt bad about not reusing something I am sure exists.

Typical needs are:
 - several operators: and or etc
 - variable number of operands
 - combining conditions to build expressions
 - serializing of expressions
 - parsing/formatting of expressions from/to strings

has somebody found something like that?

Comment: this is a very interesting question

Comment: ok yes, Functors seems like what I needed. I see I can only set one answer as the accepted one. Don't know what is the custom, to accept the first one or the more complete but later one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Apache Commons Functor](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/functor/).  E.g. [UnaryPredicate](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/functor/apidocs/org/apache/commons/functor/UnaryPredicate.html), [UnaryAnd](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/functor/apidocs/org/apache/commons/functor/core/composite/UnaryAnd.html), [UnaryOr](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/functor/apidocs/org/apache/commons/functor/core/composite/UnaryOr.html), etc.  The built-in implementations are Serializable, but I don't know about parsing from strings.  Still, I think it's a very good start towards what you want.  Also, take a look at [this IBM tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-fp.html) based on the library.

Answer (score 1):

It does sound like you might be looking for [Functors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) (aka function objects).
If so, this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651541/best-java-functor-lib-jga-commons-functor-mango-or) would be relevant, wrt. choices: Commons functor (mentioned already) is one alternative but there are others too.

All functor libs come with the framework (which is quite simple; unary, binary predicates, mapping functionality for those, combining by chaining) and basic set of functions most commonly needed.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are looking for something like the [Hibernate Criteria API](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html). The drawback is that you are tied to a database or even worse a specific persistence framework implementation. Also it does not cover all of you requirements, so I do not think this is a good choice then...

Comment: Actually, one of the things I transform these condition/expressions to, is a sql query via hibernate criteria api (the other is a lucene query, and there might be more). 

But I was thinking of something more neutral, and it would need some hability to customize for each case (subclassing or whatever I have not thought about it in depth).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Comment: isn't that used to build compilers and such?? What I was looking for is something much more simpler.