# In-memory data structure that supports boolean querying

Tags: java, data-structures, boolean-logic

I need to store data in memory where I map one or more key strings to an object, as follows:

```
"green", "blue" -> object1
"red", "yellow" -> object2
```

So, in Java the datastructure might implement:

```
Map<Set<String>, V>
```

I need to be able to efficiently receive a list of objects, where the strings match some boolean criteria, such as:

```
("red" OR "green") AND NOT "blue"
```

I'm working in Java, so the ideal solution would be an off-the-shelf Java library.  I am, however, willing to implement something from scratch if necessary.

Anyone have any ideas?  I'd rather avoid the overhead of an in-memory database if possible, I'm hoping for something comparable in speed to a HashMap (or at least the same order of magnitude).

Comment: in your example, does "green" map to object1? or is it only that "green" AND "blue" maps to object1?

Comment: "green" and "blue" are like "tags" on object1 - and you can then select objects with a boolean query on these tags.

Comment: can "green" also map to some `object3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a satisfactory solution, so I decided to cook up my own and release it as an open source (LGPL) project, find it [here](http://github.com/sanity/Athena).

Answer (score 6):

Actually, I liked the problem so I implemented a full solution in the spirit of my earlier answer:

http://pastebin.com/6iazSKG9

A simple solution, not thread safe or anything, but fun and a good starting point, I guess.

Edit: Some elaboration, as requested

---

See the unit test for usage.

There are two interfaces, `DataStructure<K,V>` and `Query<V>`. DataStructure behaves somewhat like a map (and in my implementation it actually works with an internal map), but it also provides reuseable and immutable query objects which can be combined like this:

```
    Query<String> combinedQuery = 
    structure.and(
                    structure.or(
                            structure.search("blue"), 
                            structure.search("red")
                    ),
                    structure.not(
                            structure.search("green")
                    )
    );
```

(A Query that searches for objects that are tagged as (blue OR red) AND NOT green). This query is reuseable, which means that it's results will change whenever the backing map is changed (kind of like an ITunes smart playlist).

The query objects are already thread safe, but the backing map is not, so there is some room for improvement here. Also, the queries could cache their results, but that would probably mean that the interface would have to be extended to provide for a purge method (kind of like the detach method in Wicket's models), which wouldn't be pretty.

As for licensing: if anybody wants this code I'll be happy to put it on SourceForge etc. ...

Sean

Comment: Interesting, I'm not seeing an earlier answer though - can you expand a little on the basic idea behind how this works?

Would you consider putting your code under an open source license (eg. LGPL)?

Comment: I deleted my earlier answer, sorry. I'll elaborate in my answer

Comment: Cool.  A few thoughts: It seems to create quite a few intermediate ArrayLists - I wonder if it could be done without these (perhaps returning a lazy Iterable rather than a Collection).  Caching intermediate results would be very interesting.  I'm also wondering about heuristics to determine, for And and Or, which way around the arguments should be handled for maximum efficiency.

Comment: what you're looking at is just a proof of concept, 30 minutes' worth of coding. But I have created a project at google code (http://code.google.com/p/imds4j/) and I'd be happy if you (or anybody else) contributed to it, and I'll also be happy to elaborate on your comment there.

Answer (score 1):

Would the criteria be amenable to bitmap indexing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_index ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the easiest way is simply to do a recursive filtering and being cleaver, when for instance evaluating `X AND Y` where `X` has been evaluated to the empty set.

The mapping however, needs to be from *tags* (such as "red" or "blue") to *sets of objects*.

The base case (resolving the atomic tags) of the recursion, would then be a simple lookup in this map. `AND` would be implemented using intersection, `OR` using union, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Apache Commons - Collections project](http://commons.apache.org/collections/index.html). They have tons of great stuff that you will be able to use, particularly the [CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) class for performing strong collection-based logic.

For instance, if your values were stored in a HashMap (as suggested by another answer) as follows:

```
myMap["green"] -> obj1
myMap["blue"] -> obj1
myMap["red"] -> obj2
myMap["yellow"] -> obj2
```

Then to retrieve results that match: `("red" or "green") and not "blue` you might do this:

> CollectionUtils.disjunction(CollectionUtils.union(myMap.get("red"), myMap.get("green")), myMap.get("blue"))

Comment: I don't think that would be sufficient, as it would allow only one green object, one blue object etc.

Comment: Just a quick (non-functional!) example of some tools and utilities in CollectionUtils. I'm playing with it now and will reply soon - interesting problem!

Answer (score 0):

You could map string keys to a binary constant, then use bit shifting to produce an appropriate mask.

Answer (score 0):

i truly think some type of database solution is your best bet.  SQL easily supports querying data by

```
(X and Y) and not Z
```

Answer (score 0):

this would have worked too [reusable condition/expression classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833754/reusable-condition-expression-classes)

Answer (score 0):

The Google Collections [SetMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html) looks like an easy way to get the underlying structure, then combining that with the [Maps](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) static filters to get the querying behavior you want.

Construction would go something like

```
smmInstance.put(from1,to1);
smmInstance.put(from1,to2);
smmInstance.put(from2,to3);
smmInstance.put(from3,to1);
smmInstance.put(from1,to3);
//...
```

queries would then look like

```
valueFilter = //...build predicate
Set<FromType> result = Maps.filterValues(smmInstance.asMap(),valueFilter).keySet()
```

You can do any amount of fancy building the predicate, but [Predicates](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html) has a few methods that would probably be enough to do contains/doesn't contain style queries.